# Why SQLalchemy create_all() can be reused?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have very little background knowledge about database and SQLalchemy/sqlite3, but my experiment with these tells me that create_all() can be used almost like "initialize the database if it already exists".

Here is the "form submission" part of flask webapp I wrote:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_entry = User(form.username.data,
                         form.password.data)
        db.create_all()
        add_entry(new_entry)
```

The `db.create_all()` should create a local `.db` file. If I already have that file, and I submit new data to the form, what happened is that the `new_entry` is appended to the database table instead of override that `.db` file. Can anyone confirm that this result is expected? And what is the better way to handle database initialization if this is poorly implemented?

Comment: I can't think of any case where you'd want to run `db.create_all()` on every web-request, instead do like @ThiefMaster suggests or do once in a Flask app startup task.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`create_all` indeed creates only tables that [do not exist](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html?highlight=create_all#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all). It is not intended for migrations but to create the initial structure in an empty database.

You want [alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org) for migrations, possibly via [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org)

---

Besides that, having any database structure related code in the web-facing part of your Flask app is questionable. Usually you do such things in a command-line tool (via Flask-Script or click), e.g. `python manage.py create_db`.

I disagree with your opinion of "poorly implemented". It's rather implemented in a way that stops you from doing the wrong (and possibly dangerous) thing. Imagine you rename a column. A ""smart"" `create_all` would DROP the old column (it's gone after all) and create a new one - it's impossibly for any tool to know that you renamed it instead of removing and adding one.

Comment: Could you plz elaborate on "having any database structure related code in the web-facing part of your Flask app is questionable"?

Comment: Usually you do not want to perform database structure modifications from the web interface. It's something you usually do after deploying a (new) version (which you also don't do via the web)

Comment: By "And what is the better way to handle database initialization if this is poorly implemented?", the OP didn't mean to say `create_all()` is not implemented well. He wanted to know what is a better way to do database initialization in case **his** implementation is not the best. In other words, he wanted to say: "I'd like to know how it should be done in case I did it wrong".

Comment: @Chupo_cro you are over 5 years late ;) FWIW, I answered within 2 minutes of him posting the question, so he may have edited it to be clearer within the edit-without-a-new-revision grace period (which I think is/was 5 minutes).

Comment: I am aware this was 5 years ago but answers could be **always** improved and the main purpose of this pages is to archive the informations for the future. At the moment the sentences: "I disagree with your opinion of "poorly implemented". It's rather implemented in a way that stops you from doing the wrong (and possibly dangerous) thing.", are confusing because they are not in the context of the question. The sentence 'I disagree with your opinion of "poorly implemented".', implies the OP said that `create_all()` is not implemented well but that is not what he wanted to say.